# SQL Not working in QlikView

Tags: sql-server, qlikview

I've copied an SQL code that I've previously tried in SQL Server manager and that was working with SQL Server Manager.

In QlikView I get "ErrorSource: (null), ErrorMsg: (null)"

What could be the mistake? I'm using a temp table (#Clasif1) because in the original script I have multiple Insert Into Commands.

Thanks!!

```
LOAD *;
SQL INSERT INTO #Clasif1
 SELECT de.pate_tempor, de.prod_codigo, de.liqu_numero,
 concepto = Convert(char(50),'FOB Fruta Exportacion'),
 kilos = Convert(decimal(14,2),SUM(de.dece_kilrea)),
 total_plata = Convert(decimal(14,2),sum((de.dece_kilrea/de.enva_pesone)*de.dece_fobuni))
      FROM dba.detacajemb de
     WHERE de.pate_tempor = 2015
       and de.pool_tipool = 1
  GROUP BY de.pate_tempor, de.prod_codigo, de.liqu_numero

    SELECT cla.pate_tempor, cla.prod_codigo, cla.concepto, cla.kilos, cla.total_plata, cla.liqu_numero
    FROM #Clasif1 cla;
```

Comment: if you go down the stored procedure route, check out my post on how to write them for use in Qlik. http://oneqlikatatime.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/how-to-write-sql-stored-procedures-for.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform an INSERT command from QV. You can create a stored procedure that runs your code above and call that.

```
SQL exec stored_procedure <parameters>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it better to use a stored procedure or a sql view? Is there any difference?